# Limit of two variable does not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I got this limit on my midterm: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \frac{(x^2+2x-4y^2+4y)} {(x+2y)} $$ and if I were to plug in $y=-\frac{x} {2}$ it gives me that the limit equals $\frac{0} {0}$ as opposed to the typical answer from every other path of $2$.  Is my reasoning wrong, or you can simply simplify it and not worry about the different paths?

Comment: You can simply simplify it to get $x-2y+2$, and then take the limit.

Comment: The function isn't defined when $x+2y=0$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, I am basing this off sin(x+y)/(x+y) (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291538/limit-of-frac-sinxyxy-as-x-y-to-0-0) DNE. I am assuming this reasoning cannot be applied due to the fact that it is simplifiable?>

Comment: @FrankDaTank132, usually is required that the function be defined in a neighborhood of the point minus the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \frac{(x^2+2x-4y^2+4y)} {(x+2y)} $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \bigg(\frac{(x^2-4y^2)} {(x+2y)}+\frac{2x+4y}{x+2y} \bigg) $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \bigg(\frac{(x-2y)(x+2y)} {(x+2y)}+\frac{2(x+2y)}{x+2y} \bigg) $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \big((x-2y)+2 \big) $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0,0} \big(x-2y+2 \big)=2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x^2+2x-4y^2+4y = (x+2-2y)(x+2y)$$ so $$\frac{x^2+2x-4y^2+4y}{x+2y} = \frac{(x+2-2y)(x+2y)}{(x+2y)} \\ = x+2-2y$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^2 + 2x - 4y^2 + 4y = x^2-4y^2 + 2(x+2y) = (x+2y)(x-2y) + 2(x+2y) = (x+2y)(x-2y+2)$