# Limit of $\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$ as (x,y)→(0,0)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}
$$

I did the following

$a)$ along $x$ axis, the limit is one

$b)$ along $y$ axis the limit is one

$c)$ along $y=x$ the limit is one

Since there exists more ways to approach the origin, I know I cannot conclude from the steps given above.

$d)$ along $y= -x$

$\frac{\sin(x-x)}{x-x}$ is not defined. Isn't it still possible for the function to have a limit, even though it is not defined at that point?

How do I conclude whether a limit exists or doesn't in such a case?

**EDIT**

So for,
$$
\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}
$$
Can I proceed in a similar manner and perform a substitution and state the limit is 1?

Comment: Did you try letting $(x+y) = u$ and taking $\lim_{u\to0} f(u)$? And this limit is 1 by the way.

Comment: Why is it reasonable to make that substitution?

Comment: @getaflix see my answer.

Comment: The substitution is reasonable because no matter how $x+y$ changes, it changes in exactly the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y=t$ so that $t\to 0 $ as $(x, y) \to (0,0)$ therefore we have that $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

So $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} = 1$, since this is a simple trig limit and the form is $\frac{\sin(0)}{0}$. You might substitute $u = x+y$, and $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x+y$ is obviously 0. Doing the substitution, we get $\lim_{u\to0} \frac{\sin u}{u} = 1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't covered such substitutions in our course yet and I am not sure if I am allowed to use them.

Comment: But, I guess I could check if 1 is indeed the limit using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit

Comment: @getafix substitution is a fancy way of making it simple. You can also perform the same trick without substitution, just use $x+y$ instead.

Comment: The substitution technique is not a valid proof.  It prove the limit exists as $x+y$ approaches 0,  not $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0).$  See an earlier post for a better proof. \http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291538/limit-of-frac-sinxyxy-as-x-y-to-0-0

Comment: @mattbiesecker I don't really get that proof. He says we have to "make" the function continuous, but the for the limit to exist, we need the function exists on an open interval around 0 (in this case).

Comment: Actually, you don't have to make it continuous everywhere, just along the line $y=-x,$ where $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ (similar to a removable discontinuity in 1D).  Here, We can't have "jumps" in the function in a deleted neighborhood of $(0,0).$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$$
The Taylor series of $\sin(x+y)$ at around $(0, 0)$ is
$$ (x+y)-\frac16 (x+y)^3+O\left((x+y)^5\right) $$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{(x+y)-\frac16 (x+y)^3+O\left((x+y)^5\right)}{x+y}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\left[1-\frac16 (x+y)^2+O\left((x+y)^4\right)\right]=1$$