# Why doesn't $ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} xy\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) $ exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

I've tried to get the following limit:

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} xy\sin\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right) $$

[wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29+xysin%281%2Fxy%29) claims it doesn't exist.

1. How to show that?
2. Why can't I take $z=xy$ and receive a known limit of one variable?

$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow0} z \sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) $$

Comment: Could it be because Wolfram is concerned that $\lim_{z\rightarrow0} zi \sin(\dfrac{1}{zi}) \neq \lim_{z\rightarrow0} z \sin(\frac{1}{z})$. That might explain the error Wolfram gives

Comment: Is there a way to specify that $x,y$ are real when using wolfram?

Comment: It also depends on exactly how you define limits. (If you require the function to be defined in a full punctured neighborhood of the points you approach or not.) See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283747 for some more discussions.

Comment: @TCL Surprisingly it doesn't seem to allow the usual Mathematica syntax `Assuming[Element[x | y, Reals], Limit[x*y*Sin[1/(x*y)], x->0, y->0]]`. Although when I run the query even without Assuming it gives me 0 as the result with a footnote assuming x,y are reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The limit clearly exists since $\sin$ is bounded and $xy\rightarrow 0$.

2) In this problem you can. In a problem such as $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x}{y}$ you run into trouble because you seem to suggest that it's ok to write it as $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z}{z}=1$ and that's wrong. To see why it's wrong,  $x/y$ can be arbitrarily large if you keep $x$ fixed and make $y$ smaller.

Comment: How to know when it's ok to take such $z$? or polar coordinates?